# What does blue object line mean?

Tags: objects

See attached image. I'm not aware that this object had special settings.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, figured it out. It is a rigid body joint, can be removed when you click the corresponding scene layer, and then pick the constraint panel (symbol with 2 chains) .